# Buenas noches. Tengo este mismo error en Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode, cursor

Tengo este mismo error en Visual Studio Code.  Se engrosa el cursor y me deja escribir/editar el codigo.  Ya desinstale y volvi a instalar.  Por supuesto presiono insert y se soluciona, pero al muy poco tiempo, vuelve a estar igual.  Una incomodidad ya que cada vez q tengo que hacer algo, tengo que presionar insert primero.
Probe las soluciones que ofrecian en las respuestas y no me resultaron.
Espero se entienda mi duda.
Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Presiona la tecla `Insert` de tu teclado, con eso debería de bastar.

Comment: gracias me sirvió pero en el teclado  de mac no tiene esa teclas se tiene que seralizar con la tecla **ctrl+t** para que funcione.

Comment: pero como le elimino el cursor grueso

Comment: @MateoDiazlopez  Para eso en tu Visual Code  ves a File>Preferences>Settings> y en la opción de Editor Cursor Style selecciona Line: Default, eso cambiara la apariencia de tu cursors. 
Saludos C;

Answer (score 2):

Parece que estas insertando texto. Intenta con la tecla Insert en tu teclado el cursor debe de volver a la normalidad.

Answer (score 2):

Menu Herramientas/Personalizar>Personalizar barra de herramientas o menus

en la siguiente ventana selecciona el boton de "Teclado" y escoge lo siguiente: Categorias: Todos los comandos - Comandos: Sobreescribir - Nueva tecla de método abreviado: pon el atajo que desees clic en asignar y clic en aceptar con ﻿eso habras configurado el atajo que tanto deseabas.

Con esto ya podrías saber que letra está asignada para que haga eso o cambiarla, para que lo deshabilites.

La información la saque de este foro: https://www.macuarium.com/foro/index.php?/topic/148482-activacion-tecla-insert/

Espero y te sirva, saludos